# XML-RPC and $wpdb

Tags: xml-rpc

Is it possible to use wordpress **xml-rpc** and **$wpdb** ? I need to send some params and get answer in real time ...

In this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/

I just found some info, but is there any example with $wpdb ?

Please any help ?

UPDATE:

I found some more info with methods: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending#Actions

how to implement this for full functioning ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Exactly what are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "full functioning"?

Comment: In the example, there is described method and it works. But How to make this work in real time ? Always to get value from database everytime in real time without refreshing page ?

Comment: If you need real-time updating of WordPress-generated pages without refreshing the page, you need to use [AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX).  There are a bunch of resources at the end of the article that may help you out, too.

Comment: All Says that where are lots of examples, could you show me just one ?

Comment: I just can say I need to make thing like: in facebook notifications, when where are new messages and so on...

Comment: This method calls comet ping pong.